# Is there a WebDriver Navigated event?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, webbrowser-control

The .NET WebBrowser has a Navigated event. Is there a similar event for the Selenium WebDriver? I've searched but have not found anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[WebDriver.Support](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support/2.42.0) library contains an `EventFiringWebDriver` wrapper for the `IWebDriver` interface. That wrapper provides the `Navigated` event you are looking for.

```
IWebDriver yourDriver;
...
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(yourDriver);
eventDriver.Navigated += navigatedHandler;
```

Comment: A virtual beer ! Thanks!

Comment: The Navigated event is not firing

Comment: Ah it's becaue you have to use eventDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl