# Execute code whenever page is navigated

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for a way to detect whenever the current page is navigated in selenium so I can execute some code. I know in C# and Java there are events for this, but I cannot seem to find them in ruby. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you point to an example in C# or Java?

Comment: @MladenJablanović http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156313/is-there-a-webdriver-navigated-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, from [the doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Support/AbstractEventListener):

```
class NavigationListener < Selenium::WebDriver::Support::AbstractEventListener
  def initialize(log)
    @log = log
  end

  def before_navigate_to(url, driver)
    @log.info "navigating to #{url}"
  end

  def after_navigate_to(url, driver)
    @log.info "done navigating to #{url}"
  end
end

listener = NavigationListener.new(logger)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :listener => listener
```

It's probably incomplete but it's a start.